# How to access environmental variables from javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser

I don't want to use react or another large package. This app is built with jquery. I need to access %USERNAME% from a windows environment. Surely there must be a easy way...

Comment: Environment variables can't be accessed from a web app (browser)... what are you specifically trying to do?

Comment: JavaScript in the Browser does not have access to that info

Comment: No, there must not be an easy way. Web apps are sandboxed for obvious reasons. It'd be a security nightmare if you could easily read environment variables.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apparently it is possible https://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/retrieving-environment-variable-value-in-javascript/ also found articles saying react and some other packages can access the env

Comment: Specifically I am trying to get the value of an environmental variable in javascript

Comment: "Surely there must be a easy way..." An easy way to hack into a site's visitor's computer? Would you like websites to have access to all your environment variables? You will have to politely ask the user for that information.

Answer (score 4):

Browser-hosted JavaScript doesn't have any access to the end-user's environment variables at all.

Some *build* tools may embed values from the *build environment* into the code (meaning those values reflect what was defined when the code was built, not when it runs on the browser), but that's a feature of those tools, not of JavaScript or the browser environment. (For example, projects scaffolded with Create React App have access to some environment variables from build-time; [details here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/). That may be what you were thinking of when you mentioned React.)

Comment: Ah yes, build tools was what mentioned regarding react and other packages. Thank you for clearing that up. And no hacking involved here just trying to get the computer user entering data in an app instead of hoping they  pick the correct user from a <select>.